# Very simple question regarding $X(f)$ vs. $X(j\omega)$

Tags: fourier-transform

Let's take a time domain function $x(t) = \cos( 2 \pi f_0 t) $. Its Fourier transform can be represented as

$$X(f) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \delta(f - f_0) + \delta(f + f_0) \right]\tag{1}$$

as well as

$$X(j\omega) = \pi \left[ \delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \delta(\omega + \omega_0) \right]\tag{2}$$ which was initially wrong, corrected for clarity.

Considering $ \omega = 2 \pi f $, I can interchange between the two expressions. I can tell that the $j$ in the argument of the second expression can be accounted for by the $j$ in the RHS of the first one but I can't seem to get $(1)$ from $(2)$.

Starting with $(2)$:

\begin{align}
X(j\omega) &= \pi \left[ \delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \delta(\omega + \omega_0) \right]\\
X(j 2 \pi f) &= \pi \left[ \delta( 2 \pi f -  2 \pi f_0) + \delta( 2 \pi f +  2 \pi f_0) \right]
\end{align}

I can't see how to get $(1)$ from here. I know it is very simple but I can't get any good results by Googling it up. I'd appreciate if you do not downvote my post.

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in your question. First, I suppose you mean $x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_0 t)$ instead of $\cos(2\pi\omega_0 t))$. Second, the scale factors in both equations (1) and (2) are wrong. There shouldn't be a $j$ there, and in (2) you're missing a factor of $2\pi$. So both equations you start with are wrong. Please make sure everything is correct, otherwise we don't know where to start.

Comment: Hello @MattL. Edited the mistakes. I hope it's fine now?

Comment: Yes, now it looks good, and you got a good answer right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation is right but second equation is wrong:

I would proceed in the following way to see their relation. Given $x(t) = \cos(\omega_0 t)$ with $\omega_0 = 2 \pi f_0$, first see that:
$$x(t) = \cos(\omega_0 t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{j\omega_0 t} + \frac{1}{2}e^{-j\omega_0 t}$$ 
whose CTFT is:
$$X(\omega) = \pi [\delta(\omega - \omega_0) + \delta(\omega + \omega_0)] ..... (1)$$

which follows from the transform pair: $e^{j\omega_0 t} \leftrightarrow 2\pi \delta(\omega - \omega_0)$

Then use the following property of the impulse $\delta(a x) = \frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)$ applied with $a=2\pi$ and $x=f$, and then (1) becomes:

\begin{align}
X(f) &= \pi [\delta(2\pi f - \omega_0) + \delta(2\pi f + \omega_0)]\\
X(f) &= \pi [\delta(2\pi (f - \omega_0/{2\pi})) + \delta(2\pi (f + \omega_0/{2\pi})]\\
X(f) &= \pi [\frac{1}{2\pi}\delta(f - f_0) + \frac{1}{2\pi}\delta(f + f_0)]\\
X(f) &= \frac{1}{2}\delta(f - f_0) + \frac{1}{2}\delta(f + f_0)\\
\end{align}
is the conclusion.

Note that the $j$ in the argument of CTFT $X(j\omega)$ is a notation that is equally valid in both forms as in $X(jω)$ or $X(ω)$, and it can be **omitted** for simplicity if there is no possibility of confusion, but otherwise remembered when it is necessary to underline the fact that the function is in general **complex valued**. Note that for the communications engineer the notation $X(f)$ is almost always is the choice. In either case arguments must be interpreted correctly based on the fundamental definition of the corresponding Fourier transform as given by:

$$X(jω) \triangleq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{−j\omega t}dt$$ , and 
$$X(f) \triangleq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{−j2\pi f t}dt$$

Comment: Voted up (+1). However, I still have confusions before I can accept this answer. You showed the proof relating $X(f)$ and $X(j \omega)$. Perhaps a more exact question at this point would be to compare $X(\omega)$ and $X(j \omega)$? How are they related? The original question basically asks regarding the effect of $j$ in the argument.

Comment: I guess I get it. That $j$ also comes from the same property of the impulse (i.e. $\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|} \delta(x)$ where $x=\omega$ and $a=j$. Am I right?

Comment: No. That $j$ in the argument of CTFT is a notataion that is equally valid in both forms such as $X(j\omega)$ and as $X(\omega)$ or $X(jf)$ and $X(f)$ which is usually **omitted** for simplicity but remembered when it is necessary to underline the fact that the function is in general **complex valued** as given by the integrals: $X(j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-j\omega t}dt$, $X(j f) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-j2\pi f t}dt$

Comment: Perfect. Please edit your answer and place it there, since that's what I have been looking for. Plus, where is the factor of $2 \pi$ as @MattL. stated was missing in my post?

Comment: ok let me put it, but I don't know where your $2\pi$ is...

Comment: i would not, without some differentiating subscript, write $$ X(jf) \triangleq X(f) $$ unless i intended $f \triangleq 0$ or $j \triangleq 1$.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson : ok let me correct it.